# angular-ui-router: add css class if state matched

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

simple wiki

I'd like to show an edit button in the navbar is state == 'page'

v0.2.10

```
.state('page',{
    url: "/wiki/{ns:[0-9a-zA-Z\-/_]+}/{wp:[0-9a-zA-Z\-/_]+}",
    templateUrl: "views/wiki/view.html",
    controller: "PageController"
})
```

I tried

```
<li ng-show="$state.$current.name == 'page'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Edit</button></li>
```

and

```
<a ng-class="{hidden: $state.$current.name == 'page'}" class="btn navbar-btn btn-primary" ui-sref="edit">Edit</a>
```

even

```
$state.includes('page')
```

and

```
$state.is('page')
```

Comment: those 2 questions have absolutely nothing in common

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I misread and though he was referring to ngRouter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do this all the time in projects.  The trick is to add a method on scope to check states.

```
$scope.is = function(name){
   return $state.is(name);
}

$scope.includes = function(name){
   return $state.includes(name);
}
```

Html:

```
<li ng-show="is('page')">
<a ng-class="{hidden: is('page')}">...</a>
```

---

I generally put those on root scope, but they are extremely useful.  Another thing to look into is using the `ui-sref-active` directives.  They are very good when you are creating links to states, and also want to auto-magically add a class when that state is active.

Comment: Ok that would work, but how would I attach it to the navbar? Since the navbar is on the $rootScope and does not have a controller. With ngRoute I'd define a NavbarController, nevermind, I'll try that and if it doesn't work, come back to bug you ;)

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to do this is to use `ui-sref-active` directive. The usage is pretty straight forward:

`<a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="login">Login</a>`

So when you are on `login` page it will automatically add class `active` to your `a` tag.

Comment: The best answer for my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can accomplish this with they way you've written it.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
});
```

This will make the state available in all views so you could do something like

```
$state.current.name == 'page'
```